# bash moving files with asterisk to another folder

Tags: bash, mv

I have issues trying to remove files within a folder that has similar wordings into another folder.... it's spitting back out saying that there's no such files or directory...

This is what I'm doing:

```
mv "$OUTPUT_DIRECTORY/$RANDOM6* $OUTPUT_DIRECTORY/$YEAR/$MONTH/$DAY/"
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: is this the literal command that you're issuing? you didn't close the double quote.

Comment: Also, is `$RANDOM6` supposed to be the name of the variable, or is the variable named `$RANDOM`, and you want to match the files named by that var followed by a `6` followed by any characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really want to have variable references (e.g. `$OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`) inside double-quotes to prevent the shell from overinterpreting their contents (e.g. treating spaces as word breaks rather than just part of the filename), but you *cannot* have the asterisk or the space between source and destination quoted, or they *won't* get interpreted. So here's what I'd recommend using:

```
mv "$OUTPUT_DIRECTORY/$RANDOM6"* "$OUTPUT_DIRECTORY/$YEAR/$MONTH/$DAY/"
```

Note that the first string is partly double-quoted (all of the parts with variables), and partly not quoted (the asterisk). This makes the shell apply the appropriate level and type of interpretation at each part of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Poor programming or not, but this works, i just had to remove the quotes:

```
mv $OUTPUT_DIRECTORY/$RANDOM6* $OUTPUT_DIRECTORY/$YEAR/$MONTH/$DAY/
```

All variables are issued before hand....